# How can I temporarily support a PVC pipe in use as a delivery mechanism?

Tags: pipe, mounting

I would like to use a PVC pipe to send candy to kids 10 feet from the door on Halloween. I'd put candy in the high end and it would come out the low end into the kid's candy bag. I could use help in figuring out a way to mount such a pipe without having the benefit of a railing to attach it to. I will need a free-standing solution.

I am going to need something to hold up the high end of the pipe about 5 to 6 feet and something to hold up the low end of the pipe about 3 feet. Whatever I end up with needs to be sturdy enough to not get easily knocked over, and cheap and easy to setup or quick to build. I plan to give out those Palmers chocolate eyeballs so they roll down the tube easily. I might even mount a giant eyeball on the low end of the tube so the chocolate eyeballs pop out of the pupil!

Any suggestions for what to mount the pipe on would be greatly appreciated. I'm thinking a 10 foot pipe with a 4-inch diameter.

Comment: do you own a step ladder?

Comment: That's good! for the high end I think that could work.

Comment: Throughout the years, I have seen houses leave candy in a pail by their door and children just take some candy.

Comment: A sawhorse for the low end and an A frame for the top.

Comment: This is not about home improvement.

Comment: @SolarMike It could be, or at least preventative; If the kids don't get their candy, then they   egg and tp the house..... now you've got a home improvement project.. stay safe Mike

Comment: I realize this isn't about plumbing, additions, etc, but it's something EVERY homeowner needs to think about this year. An unusual post for unusual times.

Comment: Drill a series of holes on the sides of the pipe, run a strip of LED lights down the inside attached to the top. Feed a tube from a fog machine into the the top end of the pipe, maybe a PC fan to push it down and out the holes.  Colored fog from holes in pipe. Do not forget sound effects.   MwuHaaahaaa. (*evil laugh while tapping fingers together*)

Answer (score 6):

I'd use whatever stool or chair you have around at the low end, and a stepladder or similar at the high end, possibly just leaning against the exterior wall outside the door. Cable ties, string, or duct tape would secure the pipe well. A little weight on low rungs could add stability.

I love this idea and may borrow it myself (or some Rube Goldbergian variation). A sign on the street promising "no contact" and that "we wear gloves" might add a level of comfort. Of course, I'll still don my Pennywise costume (with balloons) and emerge from the shadows alongside for a sweet/sour thrill on the turnaround.

By the way, a 4" pipe is huge and heavy (unless you use the thin-wall sewer pipe, but it's still larger than you need). 3" is probably just fine, and for your specific candy 2" would probably do. You might even get away with 1-1/2" thin-wall central vacuum pipe.

Answer (score 3):

Why not have some fun here?  See if you can find some sort of flared funnel and make the whole thing look like an Alpenhorn?   Find some small but solid-ish demon or witch model figure  to use as a support for the lower end, as tho' hesheit were holding it up.

Comment: These guys didn't want to have any fun...+1